# Flutter - iOS screen different than Android using media query

Tags: android, ios, flutter, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using the google_maps_flutter package in one of the screens on my application. Before it goes to the google maps page the user is directed to the login page (unless they are an existing user then they go to the google maps page). On Android when I use the media queries the screen size is set to 100% and looks correct. When I am testing using xcode on an iOS device the screen size has a border around it. But if I set the device height/width to 101% it is fixed and looks correctly. I took some screenshots for references below.

[image: Android Device at 100%]
[image: Iphone at 100%]

If I change the media query to 101 percent the Iphone fills in the border. I tried using SafeArea and also not using SafeArea. Has anyone had this problem before and was able to resolve it? I added the code below.

My size_config file

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static double blockSizeVertical;

  static double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  static double _safeAreaVertical;
  static double safeBlockHorizontal;
  static double safeBlockVertical;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
    blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;

    _safeAreaHorizontal = _mediaQueryData.padding.left +
        _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
    _safeAreaVertical = _mediaQueryData.padding.top +
        _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth -
        _safeAreaHorizontal) / 100;
    safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight -
        _safeAreaVertical) / 100;
  }
}
```

The google map screen

```
class MenuScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final geoService = GeolocatorService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Main Menu',
      home: FutureProvider(
        create: (context) => geoService.getInitialLocation(),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(.20),
          ),
          drawer: SideDrawer(),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(234, 234, 234, 1.0),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 100,
              width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 100,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Consumer<Position>(
                    builder: (context, position, widget) {
                      return (position != null)
                          ? googleMap(position) // If googleMap position is not null then call googleMap
                          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // Else use a circle progress indicator
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be because of SafeArea(). iOS itself a SafeArea widget so may be this differnce is occured.

Comment: I also tried blockSizeHorizontal and blockSizeVertical and had the same results : /